# If radio button is unchecked, automatically check another radio button with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a form with 2 radio buttons inside of the form. When the page with the form loads, the radio button with 'None' is automatically checked. I also wanted to be able to 'uncheck' the radio buttons, kinda like the functionality of a checkbox. I managed to do this. Now I have one more thing to do, which is the following one:

If the radio button with value 'Unconfirmed' is unchecked, the radio button with the value 'None' needs to be automatically checked again. I know that this would be easy with checkboxes, but the users can only check one of the 2 options.

My current code:

```js
var allElems = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (i = 0; i < allElems.length; i++) {
  if (allElems[i].type == 'radio' && allElems[i].value == 'none') {
    allElems[i].checked = true;
  }
}

$('form :radio').attr('data-ischecked', function() {
  return this.checked;
}); //set initial status in data-ischecked attribute

$('form').on('click', ':radio', function() {
  var status = $(this).data('ischecked'); //get status
  status && $(this).prop("checked", false); //uncheck if checked
  $(this).data('ischecked', !status); //toggle status
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label for="none">None</label>
  <input type="radio" id="none" name="myradios" value="none" />
  <label for="unconfirmed">Unconfirmed</label>
  <input type="radio" id="unconfirmed" name="myradios" value="unconfirmed" />
</form>
```

Comment: Wouldn't this make more sense to have a single checkbox for 'Unconfirmed'? If it's unchecked you know the value should be 'None'. If it's checked then the value is 'Unconfirmed'. While the JS (mostly) works on these radio buttons it will most likely confuse your users as it's completely non-standard.

Comment: yes McCrossan is right  you can use only 1 checkbox isntead of two radio buttons , still if you want to go with this one only then i ll definetly help you

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I really need to use radio buttons, because I'm working with a form in Pardot/Salesforce. So I need an answer of the users, even when the answer is 'None'. This is for a certain e-mailservice. @imdisney , if you have the time and an answer, I would very much appreciate to see your answer :)

Comment: please check your none radio button is getting uncheked or not

Comment: Yes it does. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without judging the validity of this non-standard behaviour (and not needing the initial loop):

Just add

```
if (this.id=="unconfirmed") $("#none").prop("checked", !this.checked)
```

like this

```js
$(function() {
  $("#none").prop("checked", true);
  $("#none").data("ischecked", true);

  $('form').on('click', ':radio', function() {
    var status = $(this).data('ischecked'); //get status
    status && $(this).prop("checked", false); //uncheck if checked
    $(this).data('ischecked', !status); //toggle status        
    if (this.id == "unconfirmed") $("#none").prop("checked", !this.checked)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label for="none">None</label>
  <input type="radio" id="none" name="myradios" value="none" />
  <label for="unconfirmed">Unconfirmed</label>
  <input type="radio" id="unconfirmed" name="myradios" value="unconfirmed" />
</form>
```